# How to load default Kibana dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I cann't load saved dashboard. At browser console I see:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/kibana-int/dashboard/Your%20Basic%20Dashboard?1422529331315 404 (Not Found)
```

But at Elasticsearch folder I have `kibana-int` index. How to delete all my saved dashboard, open in browser start page and create new dashboard. Now at browser I see:
[image]

Comment: there is a .kibana index (unless you have modified the kibana.yml file to specify a custom name for the index.

Answer (score 0):

there is a .kibana index (unless you have modified the kibana.yml file to specify a custom name for the index). Within the .kibana index, there are separate types -  search, index-pattern, dashboard and visualization.

All of your dashboards will be saved within the .kibana/dashboard index/type combination.   that said,    to create a default dashboard view looks at the response  to this question : [How to make our customised dashboard as default dashboard on kibana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114254/how-to-make-our-customised-dashboard-as-default-dashboard-on-kibana)