# How to make our customised dashboard as default dashboard on kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have modified my dashboard and tried saving it as home and I get the below message

Home Set This page has been set as your default Kibana dashboard

Still I am not able to load the modified dashboard as default dashboard, please suggest me on how to do it.

Comment: I can't find any default option for dashboard in kibana!

Answer (score 21):

For Kibana 4. Create dashboard with name "Default".

Change default_app_id in kibana/config/kibana.yml.

```
# The default application to load.
default_app_id: "dashboard/Default"
```

And then restart kibana to apply changes

```
service kibana restart
```

Comment: I'm trying this at the moment, I've tried all combinations of kibana.defaultAppId, default_app_id and discover/Default, dashboard/Default. Having already created the discover and dashboard called Default, the links work if typed in. But none of them seem to work. Can you advise if this still works for you?

Comment: AFAIK, this would redirect to "dashboard/Default" when the root url is accessed, but if you click the dashboard tab you still have to load one to see something. Not nice. It was reported on May 2015: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/3777

Answer (score 4):

With kibana 4.4.2 it's OK with

```
kibana.defaultAppId: "dashboard/all.dashboard"
```

With a dashboard named all.dashboard

Comment: So, this is a weird one.  When I used the name "default", or "Default", then it would not load the dashboard automatically.  But saving and then loading all.dashboard does work.  That is a strange one

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to see dashboard as a first thing when you open that is still being resolved as you can see here:
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/7626

What I did is hacked our local kibana, currently dashboard route resolver looks like this (found in `%kibana_installation_path%\src\core_plugins\kibana\public\dashboard`):

```
.when('/dashboard', {
  template: indexTemplate,
  resolve: {
    dash: function (savedDashboards, config) {
      return savedDashboards.get();
    }
  }
})
```

I just changed `savedDashboards.get() -> savedDashboards.get('System-overview')`
where System-overview is name of our dashboard (you can see it in url when you open your dashboard)

if you don't want to compile that change you will have to change it directly in the minified file which can be found here:

```
%kibana_installation_path%\optimize\bundles\kibana.bundle.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to show default dashboard in kibana :-

Steps :-

1. Copy id of the dashboard. For that go to your dashboard which you want to show as a default. At top right corner - click on SHARE after that you will see a link url something like :- http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/b55f44a0-4a78-11e7-8976-bcua7acbj?_g=()
   From the url copy id after dashboard/ like in this url id is :- b55f44a0-4a78-11e7-8976-bcua7acbj
2. Go to kibana/config/kibana.yml file and change  :-
   **kibana.defaultAppId: "discover"**  to
   **kibana.defaultAppId: "dashboard/b55f44a0-4a78-11e7-8976-bcua7acbj"**
3. Now restart kibana.service :- "**sudo systemctl restart kibana.service**"

And it is done :)